# Recursive Breadth First Search in a Matrix, fastest path (time will be spent in each matrix point)

Tags: python, recursion, graph, matrix, breadth-first-search

Consider this matrix down below, I am supposed to travel from 1 given point (user input) point to another (user input). For example it could be ocean[1][1] to ocean[2][4]. I need to find the shortest path to the endpoint. Now, this could easily be fixed by implementing BFS. But in this case it is not that simple. Consider every point in the matrix, they each have different values.

I am to sail a boat from the starting point to the end point. For each point in the matrix I have different wind-conditions which will cause the boat to travel faster through some points and slower through others. The speed in each point, and consequently the time it takes to move through one point depends on from what direction I travel into the points.

This means that I can only know the time to get through one point when actually testing it and not from the start.

With this said, my objective is no longer to find the "shortest" path, but instead the fastest.

Also there is another variable to take into consideration. I can move in 8 directions, horizontally, across and vertically (North, northeast, east, southeast etc...). Moving horizontally is sqrt(2) units of movement and moving the other directions = 1 unit of movement.

So calculating the time spent in one point you would take the direction in which you entered the point (to know how many units you moved) together with the speed in that point (calculated from the windconditions).

In order to find the fastest path I am supposed to use "recursive breadth first search", this was given as an instruction.

I know how to write a BFS in order to find the shortest path, but I do not really know where to start in order to write recursive BFS, and how to take all my variables into consideration (time etc)

Any hints on where I could gather information for this?  Also, does it sound as a logical approach to do recursive BFS for this?

This is an example matrix:  Consider all the points with "0" on it having different values (time it takes to get through that point).

```
ocean =[[0,0,0,0,0,0], 

        [0,0,0,0,0,0],

        [0,0,0,0,0,0],

        [0,0,0,0,0,0],

        [0,0,0,0,0,0],

        [0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can represent your matrix as a graph (expanding if necessary the number of nodes) and than find the shortest path using [Bellman-Ford](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm).
I'm talking about shortest path, because if you define as well your graph ant the weights of its nodes, computing the fastest path is equivalent to computing the shortest.

Using Bellman-Ford you can have also negative weights on node (for example for those node that can boost your speed), otherwise you can use [Dijkstra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) or a variant of the BFS for weighted graph.